# z-index is not working in css

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone. I have designed a website in which I have a fixed header. The website is basically for a DJ. I have developed this website in ASP.net. I am having some problems with this website. I fixed the header but the other content is now appearing in front of the header, instead of behind it. Please see the website below for how it currently appears.

http://www.spin69.com/Default.aspx

I use z-index in css but it did not work. Could you please tell me what I have to do to fix this and where my css is wrong. I am basically a developer. I designed this website using a website template which I downloaded from the internet.

Comment: Post some actual code.

Comment: what type of code you need please tell? css or html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `header` height to `180px` (or decrease `h1` height) and give `header` a `z-index:100;`.

EDIT: The only reason I've used `z-index:100;` is because you've said that you used a website template, which could have already used some `z-index` styles, so I'm guessing 100 would put it on top.

Comment: yes its done thanks sir :). I can accept answer after 8 mins so pls wait :) 
and can u pls give me some tips for web desging ?? i am basically a developer

Comment: No worries! And there are no 'tips' I can give you, except just keep practicing and looking at tutorials on how to do things. I am far from good at web development so I can't give any other tips than that.

Answer (score 0):

set h1's z-index:100; or anything above 3

the header has no z-index defined at the moment

Answer (score 0):

please use `z-index` with `position`.

Answer (score 0):

Add Z-index to header

```
header {
background-color: #000000;
height: 160px;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99999;
```

}